# Copy elision and operator overloading with C++

Tags: c++, copy-elision, return-value-optimization

I have a struct such as:

```
struct A { 
    double x,y; 
    vector<double> vec; 
};
```

I would like to overload operators such as the plus operator so that I can perform operations such as:

```
A a,b,c,d;
//do work to set up the four structs. Then:
d = a + b + c;
```

Performance is important because these operations will be performed in 'inner loops' that are run very many times. I am concerned that the line (a + b + c) will be creating temporaries and so running constructors to 'A' unnecessarily. **Running C++17, will the compiler definitely use copy elision to avoid creating temporaries?** I need to run the line "d=a+b+c" without ever running the constructor to A.

I know that if I could definitely avoid temporaries by writing:

```
d = a;
d += b;
d += c;
```

However, practically, I am about to write a lot of code with long, mathematical lines, and it would be much more convenient to be able to write things all in one line (a + b + c), rather than have to break it down into a ton of "+=" lines.

Comment: If your `operator+` requires a temporary to hold the result of `a + b`, then you're still going to be calling constructors.

Comment: look into expression templates. I doubt that copy elision can make expression templates obsolete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to [Joel Filho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11880191/joel-filho) for the suggestion to use expression templates, and the reference to the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates). That approach in the Wikipedia article worked, although it had to be modified slightly for my particular case, because I am using named class members, instead of implementing a vector. Below is an implementation.

```
template<typename E>
class AExpression {
public:
    AExpression() {};

    double Returna() const {
        return static_cast<E>(*this).Returna();
    };
    double Returnb() const {
        return static_cast<E>(*this).Returnb();
    };
};

struct A : public AExpression<A> {
    A() : a(kNaN), b(kNaN) { };
    double a,b;
    double Returna() const {
        return a;
    };
    double Returnb() const {
        return b;
    };
    
    template <typename E>
    A(AExpression<E> & expr) {
        a = expr.Returna();
        b = expr.Returnb();
    };
    
    //this method is needed because the return value of a line such as z = x + y is ASum, not A. This equality overload allows the code to convert back from type ASum to type A
    template <typename E>
    A & operator=(E const & expr) {
        a = expr.Returna();
        b = expr.Returnb();
        return *this;
    }
};

template <typename E1, typename E2>
class ASum : public AExpression<ASum<E1, E2>>  {
    E1 const& one;
    E2 const& two;

public:
    ASum(E1 const& onein, E2 const& twoin) : one(onein), two(twoin) { };

    double Returna() const {
        return one.Returna() + two.Returna();
    };
    double Returnb() const {
        return one.Returnb() + two.Returnb();
    };

};

template <typename E1, typename E2>
ASum<E1, E2>
operator+(AExpression<E1> const& u, AExpression<E2> const& v) {
   return ASum<E1, E2>(*static_cast<const E1*>(&u), *static_cast<const E2*>(&v));
}
```

With that implementation, if I run the following lines, then it executes "z = x + y" without creating any temporaries.

```
A x,y,z;
x.a = 1;
x.b = 2;
y.a = 3;
y.b = 4;

z = x + y;
//z is type 'A' and z.a = 4; z.b = 6; no temporaries are created in the line 'z = x + y'
```

Answer (score 2):

As a commenter suggested, if your `operator+` requires a temporary, you still construct a `vector` and return it, even if NRVO'd.

But, if you want to do it like that, you can reduce the amount of temporaries created:

1. Create an rvalue-qualified `operator+` implementation
2. Use the move-assignment operator to move the resulting vector into `d`, or the move constructor to make the temporary into `d` without having to

Consider this:

```cpp
A operator+(A& a, const A& b){
    A temp = /*...*/;
    return temp; // NRVO
}

A operator+(A&& a, const A& b){
    // We know a is temporary, so we can move its guts to a new one.
    a += b;
    return std::move(a); // In this case, we require the move, as it's not NRVO
}

// Then use it:
A d = a + b + c;
// What this does: 
// 1. Calls `a + b` and creates a temporary, as both are lvalues
// 2. Utilizes the same temporary to put the result of (a+b) + c
// 3. Still utilizes the same temporary to materialize the rvalue into d
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for sharing the idea. Still, it sounds like this method would still create one temporary? I really need to avoid creating any temporaries (to guarantee that, worst case, I could revert to (inconveniently) using lines with '+='). Note that my value 'd' will have been created previously.

Comment: Yes, this will create a temporary, but that's only relevant if `d`'s vector is already allocated to the correct size, thus increasing the number of allocations in the series of calls. If `d` would need to copy `a`, like in your example, you have the exact same number of allocations as move assignment (the temporary allocates, but moving into `d` doesn't)

Comment: Right, but the problem is that d would already be allocated to the correct size. I'll create d once, store it, and reuse it over and over for calculations so that I don't have to do lots of reallocations. Creating a temporary would force a new heap allocation to resize the vector every time to match the other objects, which could become expensive for these functions if they are run many times.

Comment: Then you should look at expression templates, like the other commenter pointed out. The [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) is adding 3 vectors without allocating a temporary, just like your example.

Comment: Yes, I think that you are right. I experimented with that today, and got it working. The Wikipedia example is not one-to-one identical to what I am dong, because I am doing more than just writing a Vec class. But with a bit of experimenting, got it to work. Thanks! I will write a comment soon when I have time to copy over the actual code that I wrote to solve this exact problem.